# Trimming value and text from SelectItemList using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to trim the value/text combos of a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` item in C#. I am able to do this with the code below but was wondering if it could be accomplished with Linq?

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = //function that fills the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;

foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
{
    item.Value = item.Value.Trim();
    item.Text = item.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: use list.ToList().ForEach(i=>{//do your stuff})

Comment: @Dilshod `IEnumerable<T>` has no `ForEach` method.

Comment: You could trim de values in the moment you're binding the list, instead.

Comment: @Dilshod 1) That's not LINQ 2) That is in no way superior to what he has; in fact, it does exactly the same thing but also takes the time to create and then discard a list, in addition to using a less familiar syntax and introducing closing semantics, all for literally no benefit at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is designed to define *queries*.  What you have there is not a query; it is modifying/mutating items.  As such, LINQ is not an effective tool to accomplish that, a `foreach` loop is (your implementation of one is just fine).  If you wanted to use LINQ it would be to create entirely new items, rather than modifying existing items.  That may or may not be what you really wanted to do.  If it is, then it would be:

```
list.Select(item => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = item.Value.Trim(),
    Text = item.Text.Trim(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
  Value = x.Value.Trim(),
  Text = x.Text.Trim()
  });
```

I believe this should do the trick. Why didn't yours work, by the way?